# Can we handle Push notifications coming from other apps?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Can we candle Push Notifications Coming from other apps in a custom application?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want
 to accomplish can be done via [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: But what if we don't know the specific action to be received or extras to be received?